# Qualifier must be collection

Tags: vba, ms-access, collections, compilation

I am up against an MS-Access compile error I've never seen before: "Qualifier must be collection". Can't seem to get around it making simple syntax changes. Nothing truly relevant turns up on web. Here is the offending line of code in the OnOpen event of a report:

Me.Filter = Forms!fmod_Notes.cboFilter.

Highlighted: "!fmod_Notes". The calling form is open. Why isn't it considered a member object of the Forms collection...? Thoughts...?

Thanks!

See Details, above...

Comment: I tested this and do not get error. However, does not apply filter. Instead, use WHERE CONDITION argument of DoCmd.OpenReport.

Comment: Exactly what is value of cboFilter?

Comment: A variety of different issues can trigger this error. Consider posting to a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: Sounds like `Forms` is overriden by something. Try the full name, `Application.Forms`, to confirm this

Answer (score 0):

declare variable Dim strFilter as String.
strFilter = Forms!fmod_Notes.cboFilter
Make "Debug.Print strFilter" to check the String. If the BoundColumn of your comboBox is the e.g. the PrimaryKey you have to use cboFilter.column(x) to get the right string.

If the String is ok make Me.Filter = strFilter

Answer (score 0):

Cliffhanger here answering my own question.

The mere nature of this error ("Qualifier must be a Collection"--it has a distinct vibe, wouldn't you agree... :) was a clue to me that this was going to an area of Access' architecture that--even after nearly 25 years of working in MS Access--I had no exposure to. And to me that meant I was not likely soon to come up with a resolution, even with all the helpful support I received from you folks. I was quite amazed at the quality of the support! Thank you, one and all. Very impressed...!

### My thought was to somehow repay all of you who went to that effort. My repayment takes the form of a detailed writeup of a workaround for the original approach which was to filter an Access report using its OnOpen event. Instead I've found an altogether different approach that I like much better. Please read through to the end because there's a hidden benefit to doing it this way. Here it is:

"Ever wish you knew a straightforward, user-friendly way to filter a report on one or more fields right from your current form? I submit to you a way I recently found and now use regularly, as follows:

Let's assume for an example a grossly oversimplified college admin database. You are inputting data on a form called "f_Courses" with its underlying data source, "q_Courses". The field you want to filter on is a lookup field ("lngTypeID") containing a range of course types: Undergrad, Graduate, Evening School, Online, Off-Campus, etc.

I - CREATE A COMBO BOX

1 Begin by creating a drop-down box on the very form on which you are inputting. This will be a data source (field) to be used as selection criteria in a filter query which you are going to build next. It has to be a separate field. Comparing a field to itself would only clone the recordset you are sourcing, right? At best...? What we are doing is building a second, unbound source containing the same set of values--with same datatype--as in the field being filtered on, "lngTypeID".

2 In the Wizard select "Values from another table or query" as the first option.

3 Select "Store for later use" as the second option.

4 Select the data source (table or query) from the popup list. In selecting the source I would recommend that you stick with the data source being used by the form object you are working on. If it's a query, use that rather than the underlying table. This will one day prevent your combo box from unintentionally looking at the totality of records, when the form, itself, may be looking at a limited (filtered) recordset.

5 Select the field you want to filter on (an "ID" field typically of Long Integer datatype) as field No. 1--again, the Course Type ID field. (Btw, another reason to choose the same data source as the form you are working on rather than the underlying table is that, if you choose any source other than the current, the Wizard automatically inserts the primary key field as field No. 1. And you don't want that for this exercise.

6 Select the associated string field as field No. 2 so that we humans will be able to identify the fields in the drop-down box.

7 On the Format tab of the Properties window set No. Columns to 2.

8 On the same tab hide field No. 1 in the Column Widths field by giving it zero width.

9 For column 2 allow enough width for the string field (Course Type) to be displayed.

10 Give your combo box a name in the "Other" tab of the Properties window, say, "cboFilter". Do not forget this step!

11 In the Properties window on the Data tab, find Row Source and add the word "DISTINCT" after "SELECT". This will prevent the SELECT statement from repeating every duplicate course type in your combo drop-down box. Don't forget this step, either.

12 Finally you may or may not need the label that comes with the combo box. If you wish you can give the label a caption. I simply use the caption on the command button that we are going to build later as a label.

II - CREATE A FILTER QUERY

1 Create a new query to be used as a filter using the underlying data source of your form.

2 Add the single field, "lngTypeID", from the form's data source to the grid.

3 In the "Criteria" row add the following SQL syntax:

[Forms]![f_Courses]![cboFilter]

4 Save the query, giving it a name, say, "q_TypeFilter".

5 Go to the SQL view of the query to see what Access generates from your grid:

SELECT q_Courses.lngTypeID
FROM q_Courses
WHERE (((q_Courses.lngTypeID)=[Forms]![f_Courses]![cboFilter]));

(Btw, there's a useless pair of parens here in the WHERE clause that Access generates. Don't know why Microsoft does this. Above my paygrade. But I digress...)

III - CREATE AN ON-CLICK COMMAND BUTTON

1 To launch the filtered report, create a new command button naming it, say: "cmdFilter".

2 Add one line to the OnClick event:

DoCmd.OpenReport "r_Courses", acViewPreview, "q_TypeFilter"

3 Caption the button "Type Filter"

IV - LAUNCH YOUR PREVIEW

1 Select the desired Course Type from the drop-down box.

2 Click the [Type Filter] button. It will list all--and only--the current courses by the Type you selected from the combo box."

---

That's it! Works every time. You can create more sophisticated, multi-field filters by "AND"-ing fields together in the design grid of your filter query, choosing appropriate values for the "Criteria". In this example you might add a "Required" Boolean field to your query with a "True" or "False" result. The preview listings would thus present the courses required for graduation by Type. Or those not required. You would create both a second filter query and a second command button. One filter query would match for a true criterion and the other false. The filters would need unique names, of course. Same for the two command buttons: unique names, labels ("Req" vs. "Not Req", etc.), each referencing one or the other filter in the OpenReport method of the DoCmd object.

Ok, lot of words. Undoubtedly unnecessary for most of you guys. (Remember, though, it's STEP-BY-STEP! What can go wrong...? :) And here's a side benefit from using this approach. The newly created combo box source can be used on the report, itself, to display to viewers the precise filter used in the report's preparation. Might be useful on occasion... (You can't use a field from the original data source for this purpose. The field contains variables. It would only reflect the value from the last record in the report.)  [Note: See my own comment, below, re last two sentences.]

Thanks for reading. Comments, by all means...

Comment: The last two sentences are wrong. To display the filter on the report, you DO use the subject filter field. In the above example you would use the form's lngTypeID field--the very field you're filtering on. Why? If it's on the report it has to be from the data source. (Otherwise the report will say, "Huh...!?") I use the Option Group control on the report with checkboxes. When set up correctly, a checkmark appears next to the chosen filter value. Works because every record in the filtered report shares the same filter value... :) Learning a report's content at a glance can be a real value.